# Second reverse proxy subdomain gives me weird SSL and upstream errors

Tags: ubuntu, docker, nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

My current situation is that I have an ubuntu server running docker. In that docker I run NGINX as reverse proxy, this works well for portainer, but when I try to add a second subdomain, with the same config (diff IP's ofc) I get the following error. It also gives me a 502 error in the browser.

> 2022/06/13 12:33:29 [error] 22#22: *5 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL:
> error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number)
> while SSL  handshaking to upstream, client: 172.71.94.85, server:
> prometheus.x.net, request:  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "https://172.20.0.110:9090/favicon.ico",  host: "prometheus.x.net",
> referrer: "https://prometheus.x.net/"

I use Cloudflare to manage my origin and edge SSL certificates.

This is my conf for the not working page (its exactly the same as the other working subdomain, just different IP's. I triple checked the IP's and port and it should work.

```
upstream prometheus {
        server          prometheus:9090;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name prometheus.x.net;
        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen          443 ssl;
        listen          [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;
        ssl_client_certificate  /etc/ssl/cloudflare.crt;
        ssl_verify_client       on;
        server_name     prometheus.x.net;

        location / {
                # Allow websockets
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

                # Default headers
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass https://prometheus;
        }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

EDIT: I use a .conf file for each subdomain in the conf.d folder, idk if that matters?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out a minute after posting. Should've spent a minute longer trouble shooting.

Unlike portainer, this application doesn't have built in HTTPS, so with my current config NGINX was trying to locally reach the application using HTTPS, while it only supports HTTP.

`proxy_pass https://prometheus;`

should be

`proxy_pass http://prometheus;`

Comment: Don'r forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer.